# Gmail: How to send a email 12times to same receiptent

Tags: gmail

Is there any automated way..that I can send same email 12 times to same receiptent..

Comment: Using apps script it could be done.

Comment: how todo that...

Comment: any extension..like chrome or firefox addons that would help

Comment: If I have to write it using GAS, I would use a loop and use `MailApp` You may check Google Apps Script official documentation.  Regarding extension, sorry I don't know about suitable extension for this purpose.